# Measuring time critical code snippets with Stopwatch

Tags: c#, timer, performance-testing, stopwatch

So i'm trying to analyse the following code snippet written by me:

```
private void Scrn_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    watcher.Start();

    try
    {
        using (Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Program.ScreenParameters.ScreenshotWidth, Program.ScreenParameters.ScreenshotHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
            {
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Program.ScreenParameters.FromX, Program.ScreenParameters.FromY, 0, 0, size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpScreenshot.Width, bmpScreenshot.Height);
                var data = bmpScreenshot.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpScreenshot.PixelFormat);
                var depth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(data.PixelFormat) / 8; //bytes per pixel

                var screenshotData = new byte[data.Width * data.Height * depth];

                //copy pixels to buffer
                //Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, screenshotData, 0, screenshotData.Length);

                Parallel.ForEach(Program.slaveList, slave =>
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, slave.image, 0, screenshotData.Length);
                    slave.Notify();
                });

                bmpScreenshot.UnlockBits(data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Debug(ex);
    }

    watcher.Stop();
    logger.Debug("Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': " + watcher.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    watcher.Reset();
}
```

This is a System.Timers.Timer which is ticking every 30 ms. It makes a screenshot, gets the bytes and distributes them to every slave connected to my system.
So I'm trying to measure that whole process to get an idea of the FPS i can reach. My Stopwatch continusly shows values between 0 - 30 ms, which is perfectly fine. But I'm irritated because i'm getting a lot of measurements which show 0.
For Example:

```
2018-11-05 13:56:59.9248 [16] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 1,9086 
2018-11-05 13:56:59.9404 [19] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0 
2018-11-05 13:56:59.9716 [17] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.0028 [15] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.0496 [16] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 10,9468 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.0652 [17] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 10,9468 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.0964 [18] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.1432 [22] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0,8427 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.1588 [19] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0,8427 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.1900 [18] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 0 
2018-11-05 13:57:00.2368 [23] DEBUG: Iteration-Time 'Scrn_Timer_Tick': 7,0265
```

I just cant get in which case the stopwatch should show 0. I mean, in my understanding the processing between the measurement points is always atleast running, and if it aborts i would catch an exception, but i'm not seeing anything.
So can anybody help me explaining how this 0 measurements are appearing?

Comment: Try `watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds` - I guess there may be some kind of problem when converting the value to TimeSpan.

Comment: Why is your `watcher` declared outside of the method? Try to change it to a variable thats defined inside the method

Comment: @RandRandom thank you very much! When i declare a new stopwatch in the method, it will not show any 0 measurements. I'm still not sure why, but its working!

Comment: Is there some kind of multi-threading issue? Might the `Scrn_Timer_Tick` be called from multiple places? Having `watcher` declared outside the method means multiple invocations operate upon the same variable.

Comment: Nope, it's just a ElapsedEventHandler of a System.Timers.Timer running at an Interval of 16 ms. Which seems to indicate that the Stopwatch itself maybe is too slow resetting or something like that.